# How to redirect to real URL when virtual URL request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

How to redirect to real URL when virtual URL request:

Example:

```
virtual URL : {language}/{action}              >> English/Index
real URL    : {language}/{controller}/{action} >> English/Home/Index
```

I tried this and did not give what I wanted:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
      url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { lang="ar", controller = "Homes", action = "Index"}
    );
}
```

Comment: can use "Attribute Routing"

Comment: how i do it .. ?

Comment: Try to add more information to give context to your question (what have you already tried, are you receiving errors, etc.). The more detailed your question, the better your chances are of receiving quality answers.

Comment: ok ............

Comment: I see "Homes" as the controller name, shouldn't it be "Home" (singular)?

Comment: Also, if you set "{language}/{controller}/{action}" as the url property of your customized route, you'll never catch your case... you should write "{language}/{action}", and then new { lang="ar", controller = "Homes", action = "Index"} as your default field

Comment: please , give me example for i add this